# What and where is TDocument in MongoDB Java API

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

In the [MongoDB Java API](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html), what is a `TDocument` and where is the documentation for it? I know that it is used in generics, so it has to be either a class or an interface. But `TDocument` is not anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a type parameter, the same as `E` in [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)